# How to await an async method which isn't expected to return

Tags: c#, asynchronous, server, async-await

I'm making a TCP server. I'm using async/await to handle the multi-threading. The methods I am using for listening to incoming clients and there subsequent messages look a bit like this:

```
private static async Task Listener()
        {
            while (Online)
            {
                TcpClient socket = await tcpListener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
                OnReceivedTcpClient(socket);
            }           
        }
```

As you can tell, this method isn't expected to return anytime soon. The question I have is regarding how I should call this listener method. Currently the way I'm doing it is this:

(Console App)
In Program.cs within Main, I call Server.Start()

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Title = "Server (Prototype)";

            Server.Start(100, 26950);

            ConsoleKeyInfo input;
            do
            {
                input = Console.ReadKey();

                // check input and do stuff
                }
        }
            while (input.Key != ConsoleKey.C);  
            
        }
```

Server.Start initilises some values and then calls an event which in turn calls the listener

```
private static event EventHandler<EventArgs> StartEvent;
private static void OnStartEvent() => StartEvent?.Invoke(null, new EventArgs());

public static void Start(int maxClients, int port)
        {
            Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Starting server...");
            Init(maxClients, port);
            OnStartEvent();
        }

private async void ServerOnStartEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {           
            Online = true;          
            Console.WriteLine($"Server started on port {Port}");
            await Listener();
        }
```

If I had called await Listener(); inside of Server.Start then that method would need the async keyword, and it would have to either return void (Which I know is not an ideal design) or return a Task which then means I would have to call _ = Server.Start() inside program.cs (Which also is not great design).

So my question is, is my solution a good way of awaiting an async Task method and are there better ways to go about it?

Comment: Async/await isn’t for multithreading. If you need another thread to run in the background then create another thread. That’s the proper way.

Comment: Ahh I see I've made the mistake of thinking that multi-threading and asynchronous programming are the same. I'll research whether I should be multi-threading instead.

Comment: @Sami Kuhmonen - excellent point.  Here's a great article that helps clarify when to use Async/Await, and when Threading might be more appropriate: https://www.baeldung.com/cs/async-vs-multi-threading

Comment: I've been doing a bunch of reading on this. Now correct me if I'm wrong, but async tasks use the threadpool if the caller thread does not have enough resources. This would suggest that async tasks are indeed multithreaded, but only when necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I usually deal with this is to also add a `Stop`-method. So Start launches the task and saves it in a field. the stop method requests the task to stop (by whatever means), and returns the task that was stored.

So the caller can await the result from the stop method, and once the task completes, the caller can be sure any resources are cleaned up etc.

A variant would be to let the Start method return something like a [IAsyncDisposable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iasyncdisposable.disposeasync?view=net-5.0), that could allow the using-statement to automatically stop and wait for cleanup when going out of scope.

Example:

```
public class MyClass
    volatile bool stopRequested; // or use CancellationTokenSource
    Task task;
    public void Start() => task = Task.Run(DoWork); // Should probably make this "longRunning"
    public void DoWork(){
        while(!stopRequested){
            // Do something that take a limited amount of time.
        }
        // Do cleanup
    }
    public Task Stop(){
        stopRequested = true;
        return task;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @JonasH for the reply! Would you be able to provide a code example?